# Genetic algorithms for platform game (Mario like)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, 2d-games

I’m making an IA for a platform game (mario like) and I want to use an GA. I’m struggling with the inputs to give to my IA (which describe the state of the game) and with the genes format. Have anyone tried GA on this kind of game ? Or knows good ressources about it ?

Comment: The question is far too broad to give an answer. What do you want genetic algorithms to generate for your game? If you don't know, then we can't help you.

Comment: I want an IA which can finish a level of a platformer game, for example, move the Mario to the ennd of the level with dying

Comment: That's still pretty broad.